# What is the role of getIn with Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

What exactly is the role of getIn here? Does it simply read and assign values from the defined fields?

```
{fileds.map(({ formikRef, ...input }) => (
    <TextField
       key={formikRef}
       helperText={
       getIn(formik.touched, formikRef)
                    ? getIn(formik.errors, formikRef)
                    : ''
                }
       value={getIn(formik.values, formikRef)}
      {...input}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
    />
))}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`getIn` is a utility function included in Formik. You can use it to extract a deeply nested value from an object by using its path. The path is denoted using dot syntax to access object properties and square brackets to access arrays.

For example:

```
var exampleFormValues = {
  people: [
    {
      name: 'Alice',
      contactDetails: {
        email: 'alice@example.com',
        mobilePhone: '07123 456789'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      contactDetails: {
        email: 'bob@example.com',
        mobilePhone: '07999 999999'
      }
    },
  ]
};

// this will return 'alice@example.com'
var emailOfFirstPerson = getIn(exampleFormValues, 'people[0].contactDetails.email');
```

It's basically the same as the `get` function from lodash, documented here: https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Comment: It looks like a correct answer. Wonder why people ask questions and then show no reaction to someone who takes the time to answer that (accept the answer, upvote, comment, ...)

Comment: Great answer. A nice thing about this utility function is that the path string it takes will be identical to the `Field` or `FieldArray` name prop for a given field. It makes manually accessing deeply nested fields that formik is tracking easy since you likely already have a string to target the field that you're passing to a formik component.